# How many times can I visit the UK?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, uk-citizens, lhr

I’m a u.s citizen I was in the UK for (2017-2018) school year on a tier 4 visa. I also visited during the Christmas break for three weeks, I’m planning to come back on March to look at Law schools for a week since I’m planning to go to Law School in Scotland. Should I have any problems with border security or am Is it just my anxiety?

Comment: Nobody knows, sounds reasonable to me. You could be asked why you didn’t do the law school visits during your December visit. Just carry good evidence along and I believe you will likely be fine. You can visit as many times as you want **provided you are let in**, no law about number of times.

Comment: Thankyou so much I appreciate it! I will probably bring papers proving my current enrollment in school and return ticket